# Is it secure to put the Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo-DB-API connection string in a Xamarin App?

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, security, azure-cosmosdb

I want to publish an app which contains the MongoDB Driver and the connection string I got from Microsoft Azure CosmosDB. Is it secure enough or do I additionally make an API? I know you shouldn't do that, but I am a bit confused about the "MongoDB-API".

Comment: No it is not secure to pass your sever connection string to everyone that downloads your app

Comment: Isn't it an API?

Comment: Isn't what an API?

Comment: the "Azure Cosmos DB-API for Mongo DB". Sorry for these kind of questions, but I am new at programming

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a server side component (could be using any number of different technologies) that your app communicates with. This component should have a strongly defined contract that the APP communicates with. This also communicates with Cosmos. This was I can't just read the connection string and delete all your data remotely.

Comment: How about Rotating the Keys? E.g. said in this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Scalable--Service-Data-with-CosmosDB-for-Mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not secure to store connection details on the client. For reference, [the documentation is here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection#connect-via-driver). The example given in the documentation is in Python, but that does not change the main point:

```py
import pymongo
import dns # required for connecting with SRV

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test?w=majority")
db = client.test
```

Note the connection requires you to specify credentials. Once those credentials are stored and distributed embedded in an app, you must assume that the whole world knows them. If it were OK for the whole world to be able to connect to the database with those credentials, why would you need them in the first place?

So, your app needs a data access layer whose job is to authenticate app users and carry out queries required by those users' requests and relay the results in way the app understands.

Comment: Then I don't have a choice....